# adding fragments over the same FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been using `Fragments`, programmatically .Initially i add one (first one) over a `FrameLayout` by id of `R.id.contentframe` and later during fragment changes i am justing `replace`-ing the new fragment over this one.

Now i have a case where i want to `add` a new fragment over this and then i have a couple of fragment changes which would happen in this fragment layer.These fragments are nothing but fragments which were already their but their new instances are utilised in a different manner to show the user.Inherently,the other fragments which i had were also `replace`- ing over the `R.id.contentframe` so i thought these replaces would happen over the new `Fragment` instances layer but i see since both were using code

```
fTrans.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "LOGIN");
```

this code seem to replace the fragment in the lower layer of fragments and not the new instance of fragment over this.

I want the behaviour described above how can this be achieved?

Thanks in advance

My xml layout :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentframe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
        android:layout_width="260dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@color/theme_black"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:headerDividersEnabled="true"
        android:listSelector="@color/theme_yellow"
         />



</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. Can we back up and look at the *effect* you want to acheive by providing drawings or mockups of some kind? It sounds like fragments aren't the right solution to do what you want.

Comment: give me some time.O will try and create a mockup.in sha Allah